# AWS RDS Oracle Access Control

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, rds

RDS Oracle does not support on-prem AD authentication. How do you control/monitor/track what DB users/admin do on the Oracle RDS instances?

Comment: This question needs a lot more details than it has. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but you can enable cloudTrail on your db instance, to monitor api calls and db access.

Please read more on: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html